# Building a django app in Travis CI not successful

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, travis-ci

I am trying to integrate Travis CI with Django application. But I am getting the following error

```
Successfully built 9b60427cea1c
Successfully tagged 3_recipe_app_app:latest
WARNING: Image for service app was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Creating 3_recipe_app_app_run ... 
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
OK
./app/settings.py:23:80: E501 line too long (81 > 79 characters)
./app/settings.py:89:80: E501 line too long (91 > 79 characters)
./app/settings.py:92:80: E501 line too long (81 > 79 characters)
./app/settings.py:95:80: E501 line too long (82 > 79 characters)
./app/settings.py:98:80: E501 line too long (83 > 79 characters)
ERROR: 1
The command "docker-compose run app sh -c "python manage.py test && flake8"" exited with 1.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

**.travis.yml**

```
language: python
python:
  - "3.6"

services:
  - docker

before_script: pip install docker-compose

script:
  - docker-compose run app sh -c "python manage.py test && flake8"
```

**.flake8**

```
[flake8]
exclude =
  migrations
  __pycache__,
  manage.py,
  settings.py
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
LABEL maintainer="hans"
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app /app
RUN adduser -D user
USER user
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

I am not sure how this error occured. I tried this in several times but still the same error throws up. How can I solve this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... you've configured the flake8 linter to be run on your code.

The linter has been configured to consider lines longer than 79 characters (the default) to be too long, and your settings file contains such lines:

```
./app/settings.py:23:80: E501 line too long (81 > 79 characters)
./app/settings.py:89:80: E501 line too long (91 > 79 characters)
./app/settings.py:92:80: E501 line too long (81 > 79 characters)
./app/settings.py:95:80: E501 line too long (82 > 79 characters)
./app/settings.py:98:80: E501 line too long (83 > 79 characters)
```

Shorten those lines, or configure flake8 to allow longer lines.

Comment: I tried to fix this adding max-line-length = 85
extend-ignore = E501 in .flake8 file. But didnt work

Comment: It was my mistake too.. .flake8 was in not project directory. Your idea gave me more things to understand. Please upvote the question too... Thanks for your support